# Mule ESB Transform Message xml conversion

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I am facing one issue while `xml` format conversion in mule transform message.

I am having one input `xml` file.

and I have to convert the input `xml` to output `xml` where the node structure is different and node names are different.
I used data transform message for this conversion, But at one point, it is showing expected format is object and found string.
Can any one please help me for the same.

> "Type mismatch
>        found :name, :string
>     required :name, :object (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException). Message payload is of type: WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler"

```
input payload 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <AGREEMENT>
  <details>
  <newTransaction>N</newTransaction> 
   <type>ddd</type> 
   </details>
 </AGREEMENT>

output Payload

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
<TestHeader xmlns="TestWebService">
    <Username>aaa</Username>
    <Password>aaa</Password>
</TestHeader>
 </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <AGRMNT>
        <testId>
        <_-Test_Agrmnt- SEGMENT="1">
            <transaction>N</transaction>
        </__-Test_Agrmnt->
    </testId>
  </AGRMNT>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

DataWeave code

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
 %namespace soap http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/

{
 soap#Envelope: {
    soap#Body: {

        AGREEMENT: {

            testId: {
            '_-Test_Agrmnt-': {

                    transaction: payload.AGREEMENT.details.newTransaction as   :string
                    }
                }
            }
        }}
```

Comment: can you provide your xml input and output?

Comment: Your output file is not well formatted. please post expected output

Answer (score 0):

I have got following output with your input and script

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <AGREEMENT>
      <testId>
         <_-Test_Agrmnt->
           <transaction>N</transaction>
         </_-Test_Agrmnt->
     </testId>
   </AGREEMENT>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The only change is adding --- in script

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
                %output application/xml
                %namespace soap http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
                ---
                {
                 soap#Envelope: {
                    soap#Body: {

                        AGREEMENT: {

                            testId: {
                            '_-Test_Agrmnt-': {

                                    transaction: payload.AGREEMENT.details.newTransaction as :string
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }}}]]>
        </dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
```